# What is difference between Global keyword and array in php

Tags: php

I have to change a script to run on a server with Global Variables disabled.

so I am wondering if this is not working:

```
function setData(){
  echo $GLOBALS['data'];
}
```

Will this work ?

```
function setData(){
  global $data;
  echo $data;
}
```

If no, what is the solution ?

Comment: There is no `$_GLOBAL` but `$GLOBALS`. No difference. Both would work. You cannot disable any of these.

Comment: When you say "Global Variables are disabled" do you mean "register_globals"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)? That doesn't disable all globals, it just disables the setting of global variables from request parameters.

What that means is, if someone goes to a page like this: `index.php?admin=1` then in `index.php` the global variable `$admin` will be set to `1`. Which you generally don't want. It doesn't stop global variables working.

As Col. Shrapnel said in the comments, `$_GLOBALS` won't work, because the name of the array is [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way for you would have been to simply try it... to answer you question: i'm pretty sure `global $data;` should work anyway - i don't know a possibility to disable this, but maybe there is one to disable the `$_GLOBAL`-array (i'm not sure at this, but if i'm not missunderstanding your question, you're using such a possibility - or, as Skilldrick said, you're meaning something completely different)

Comment: that is it, i can't use $_GLOBAL in my server and i was just wondering why ?

Comment: @Omeid did you not read the first comment on your post? There is no `$_GLOBAL` just `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: @Skilldrick, did you check the code that its now $_GLOBALS not $_GLOBALS ? i am just a bit in rush so i allways miss the S ;)

Comment: @Omeid. Pause. Breathe. Read. `$GLOBALS`. No underscore.

Comment: @skilldrick: LOLZ now i got it! you know `$_SERVER,$_SESSION,$_GET,$_POST` all these super globals are in this format so i keep thinking of that, thanks for pointing out anyways.